# QOpenGLFunctions not const correct

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, constants

Assume a `QOpenGLFunctions` object is a member of a class. Since the `gl*` methods are not marked **const** where appropriate, they cannot be invoked in a **const** method even if they may make no state changes at all.

Am I using `QOpenGLFunctions` wrong?

Comment: Doesn't a C++ class method `const` qualifier merely state, that it doesn't modify any of the class members only; IIRC it's perfectly valid for a `const` method to modify data outside of the class instance.

Comment: @datenwolf The QOpenGLFunction is a member of the class that holds all the gl functions. You can't invoke non-const methods of members of "this" in a const method.

Comment: Well, if you insist on using wrapper then the `QOpenGLFunctions::gl…` methods are not really constant: They may change the OpenGL context and since some OpenGL function pointers are tied to the context that transparent context switch may mandate the alteration of the internal function mapping table. Hence they're not const. – However you can still access the unwrapped global scope OpenGL functions, if you take care the right context is active and function pointers match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat philosophical, but I could argue that you're using it "wrong". By making `QOpenGLFunctions` a member of your class, you're saying that the OpenGL functions are part of your class state. Which they are really not. They are something your class **uses**, but they are not **part of** your class.

You have a couple of options to fix this:

1. You can add a `mutable` to the member definition (`mutable QOpenGLFunctions m_...`).
2. You can make the member variable a pointer to `OpenGLFunctions`, and allocated the object in the constructor of your class.

Using `mutable` always feels kind of hacky to me, even though it has legitimate uses. I clearly prefer option 2 in this case. Beyond solving your const-correctness problem, it also expresses the weaker coupling between your class and `OpenGLFunctions` that really matches the correct relationship I explained in the introduction.

Comment: Why would changing it to a pointer make a difference? The functions would still need to be marked const, right?

Comment: No. If your class contains a pointer to a `OpenGLFunctions` instance, you can call non-const methods on it from a const method of your class. It makes sense, because it's not part of your object anymore.